# Material UI theme (JetBrains) don't change sidebar style

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

The sidebar doesn't change to the desired style and always remains gray.

How to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: IDE and Editor themes are completely unrelated and are configured in different places. IDE theme can be changed [here](http://i.imgur.com/fo3lPU6.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I've done this several times but it does not help. Also i try restart IDE - without result

Comment: You may want to file a bug to the theme designer.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, if nobody dont help here, I'll try to write them

Comment: @CrazyCoder, omg i found solution)

Answer (score 5):

**I found a solution:**

Go to View -> Toolbar  and then select the highlighted icon as on the screenshot below[image]

It was difficult for me :) I spent on this little thing a few hours

Comment: This happens to me after every major PhpStorm update and I always forget how to get it back until I find this answer. Thanks!